# iTunesConnect hangs on TestFlight

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

I'm trying to reach TestFlight on iTunesConnect but it keeps only the loading spinner and do not show anything. I've tried with Chrome and Safari without success.

http://prntscr.com/8sv799

In my other application on the very same account everything works correctly.

I've already written to support waiting for their response.

Comment: Did you clear cache in Safari? https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4448839?tstart=0

Comment: Yes, tried it without success.

Comment: I have this issue now as well. Did you get your issue solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was resolved from the support team. They didn't provide me full details what caused this, however after sending them needed information(including page source code) they fixed it on next day.

So if you experience the same, I advise you to contact them(via iTunesConnect).